# UPDATE Postgresql where row...else delete

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, delete-row

Here's what I have:

col1 | col2

 ------| ------ 

  a.....| x......
  a.....| y......
  b.....| y......
  c.....| y......
 d.....| y......
 d.....| x.....

Here's what I want:

col1 | col2

 ------| ------ 

  a.....| x......
 b.....| y......
 c.....| y......
d.....| x......

So the idea is to remove any row where col1 is paired with y when it is also paired with x in a different row.

I'm very new to sql! Closest thing I could fine is this, but it's not helping...https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Thanks :-)

Comment: Are there more columns in the row? And do you actually want to delete rows from the table or just a `SELECT` statement to retrieve your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
DELETE FROM your_table_name
WHERE col2 = 'y'
  AND col1 IN (SELECT col1
              FROM your_table_name 
              WHERE col2 = 'x')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Igor's answer, you could then add a trigger to do this automatically if that is part of your workflow.

```
create or replace function auto_delete_y_rows() returns trigger as $$
begin
  delete from tbl
  where col2 = 'y'
  and col1 = new.col1;

  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger auto_delete_y_rows
after insert or update on tbl
for each row
  when (new.col2 = 'x')
execute procedure auto_delete_y_rows();
```

Comment: At this time I do not require the additional code, although I will save it for future reference. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### Select good rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (col1)
       col1, col2  -- add more columns
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY col1, col2;
```

Short and fast, and it's easy to include more columns. Explanation and links for the technique:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

#### Delete bad rows

```
DELETE FROM tbl t1
USING  tbl t2
WHERE  t2.col1 = t1.col1
AND    t2.col2 = 'x'
AND    t1.col2 = 'y'
```

`IN` is notoriously slow with big lists.
Add the table another time with the [`USING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html) clause (self-join) to make this shorter and faster.
Verify performance with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to delete rows?  Or do you just want a query that returns what you want?

For the data you have provided, the following gives you the results you want:

```
select col1, min(col2) as col2
from t
group by col1;
```

An alternative way of expressing your logic is something like:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (t.col2 = 'Y' and
            exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 = 'X')
          )
```

Comment: Ha, the first worked after I changed min to max. Never would have thought min and max working on text variable, but there you have it.  

I don't *have* to delete them, but I need to either delete the rows or store the output into a new table.